# compiling with emacs inside vagrant -- and next-error

Tags: emacs, vagrant

I'm using vagrant to provide a development environment (ubuntu 16.04 on a 17.04 host).  So I develop in emacs on my local machine (17.04) in order to have X and other integration, but compile on the vagrant guest.

```
M-x compile
vagrant ssh -c "cd /vagrant; make -C . -j 6 -k"
```

And that works, but now `next-error` fails, because emacs is reading the `make: Entering directory /vagrant` at the beginning of the buffer.

Is there a way to tell emacs the local name of the directory or make the name I want to report for emacs?  Or another way to coordinate these two?

Making a symlink '/vagrant' is too intrusive a hack...

Comment: If you somehow use tramp to get into the vagrant guest (which might be as simple as `C-x C-f /ssh:vagrant-guest-name:/vagrant RET`), then you can run commands inside the guest transparently.  In particular, you can just run `M-x compile RET make -C . -j 6 -k RET` from the tramp buffer and it should just work.

Comment: I should say I'm not super familiar with vagrant.  My understanding is that it can spin up a virtual machine with an ssh server running in it, so you should be able to connect to that ssh server from the host system.  If so, you can just treat it like any ssh server.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect answer by any means.

In the end, I created a symlink from /vagrant to my working directory.  This works for me because I only do this for one project and because it is my machine(so I am the only user doing this).  It is therefore an inadequate solution beyond my special case.

I was not able to get tramp to work well for me.  Maybe it's possible, but GNU make really wants to start by stating where it is compiling, which is generally a good thing.  Tramp only affects how I access the guest (vagrant) host.